# HDMI splitter + VGA converter

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

Before I start buying components, I was wondering if anyone had any experience with the following:

- HDMI out from a raspberry pi going to a HDMI splitter (externaly powered) (1x2)
- First HDMI going to a TV (thru HDMI in)
- Second HDMI going into a HDMI --> VGA converter (externaly powered)
- VGA cable from the converter goes to a relatively shitty widescreen (vga in)

Am I right in that this should work (depending on quality of individual components), or am I missing something?

(If anyone wonders, my aim here is to be able to watch xbmc in two rooms at the same time, with one room being silent due to VGA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be an issue.

Since you have external power, it suggest that these are true converters which convert the signal from digital to analog. In these types of situations my biggest headache is finding a brand and a model that is reliable.

"Adapter" types which are passive, either don't work or fail quickly. Some in minutes, as the IC burns out. Active Converters on the other hand do much better. I like Startech.

On the splitter, do make sure it is a *splitter* and not a switch of some sort.

Without knowing exact models, I will say the birds-eye of your approach should work, although it is ugly from a professional perspective. So I do hope this is only for personal fun.

Comment: It is indeed for personal fun (to the extent of being pointless, because I can hear my TV from the second screen). I think I'll give Startech a shot. Thank you.